# Python Gstreamer Shmsrc Multiprocessing Callback Failing

Tags: python, gstreamer

Problem:
I am trying to use gstreamer shmsink/shmsrc to share a live video between multiple python processes. While this seems to work for one case with a simple downstream pipeline a more complex appsink pipeline is failing to pull samples and or callback.

Base code:

```
# Upstream Pipeline, Process 1:
pipeline_String = "v4l2src do-timestamp=true ! image/jpeg, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)30/1 !\
            jpegdec !\
            queue !\
            identity!\
            shmsink wait-for-connection=0 socket-path=/tmp/tmpsock  shm-size=25000000 sync=true"

# Working Downstream Pipeline, Process 2:
pipeline_String = "shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/tmpsock do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)30/1 !\
            glimagesink name=sink"

# Non Working Downstream Pipeline, Process 3:
pipeline_String = "shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/tmpsock do-timestamp=true ! video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)30/1 !\
            videoconvert !\
            videorate ! video/x-raw,format=(string)RGB, framerate=(fraction)30/1 !\
            appsink name=sink"
```

```
Process 3 Launch Code & Callback:

pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(pipeline_String)
appsink = self.pipeline.get_by_name("sink")
appsink.set_property("emit-signals", True)
appsink.connect("new-sample", self.__on_new_sample)
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

 def __on_new_sample(self, app_sink):
        print("called")
        sample = app_sink.pull_sample()
        print("sample?")
```

Result:

- Process 1 & 2 pipelines work. Process 3's never triggers callback. Even if the callback is manually triggered app_sink.pull_sample() never completes.
- If Process 1 is not active when Process 3 is started. Process 3 fails as expected with standard can't find tmpsock message.
- If Process 1 is killed Process 3 app_sink.pull_sample() will complete and pass with no data to process failing the next command.

Tried:

- It does not matter if Process 2 is active or inactive with process 3. Also other terminal sessions can launch gstreamer instances with access to tmpsock no issue.
- Inclusion of loop = GLib.MainLoop() & loop.run() will either cause the process to fail or has no apparent effect. (High suspicion this is the issue though)

```
# Original working example I built off Of:

import gi
from threading import Thread

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version("GstApp", "1.0")

from gi.repository import Gst, GLib, GstApp

## Gstreamer INIT
Gst.init(None)

main_loop = GLib.MainLoop()
main_loop_thread = Thread(target = main_loop.run)
main_loop_thread.start()

pipeline = Gst.parse_launch("v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 !  videoconvert ! videorate ! video/x-raw,format=RGB, framerate=5/1 ! appsink name=sink")
appsink = pipeline.get_by_name("sink")
pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

appsink.set_property("emit-signals", True)
appsink.connect("new-sample", __on_new_sample)

def __on_new_sample(app_sink):
    sample = app_sink.pull_sample()
    caps = sample.get_caps()
```

Comment: Update:
It appears the  videoconvert ! videorate ! "caps" ! region is where the issue is occurring. Removing the videorate part seems to make the pipeline deliver to the appsink and callback as intended.